# In python, how can you delete the third forth and fifth line of a text file?

Tags: python, file, text, lines

There was another question about deleting the first three and the last line, they used `.writelines()`, but that only work if you want to delete the outside lines, not delete lines in the the middle.

Any ways of deleting multiple specific lines from anywhere in a text file in python?

Please, Please, PLease Help!!

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
with open('input.txt') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(line for lineno, line in 
                        enumerate(f, 1) if lineno not in (3,4,5))
```